# Regex for PHP - similar to IP pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression which consist of: 1-3 digits and optional dot. It is something like IP pattern. I want my regex to allow the following:

**192**

**192.**

**192.168**

**192.168.**

and **NOT** the following:

**192.1688**

This is what I have so far:

```
preg_match('/^((\d{1,3})(\.?))+$/', $string);
```

But it still allows me to have more than 3 digits. Any suggestions how to fix the regex?

Comment: [`^([0-9]{1,3}\.)*([0-9]{1,3}\.?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/kV7zW5/1)

Comment: Maybe [`^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})*\.?$`](https://regex101.com/r/vC9yX0/1)? How many digit groups should be supported? Do you need the number to be in the range between 0 and 255 as in IP? Try [`^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?))*\.?$`](https://regex101.com/r/vC9yX0/2) then.

Comment: Hey @stribizhev, do you think my  regex should/will work

Comment: If you mean the first one, yes, but it requires more steps to find a match than the pattern I suggested.

Comment: https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/PHPVerbalExpressions is a library that you will probably find useful :) it makes regex like this way easier

Comment: Oh, yes, because the first group is _optional_(in some cases). Thanks @stribizhev

Comment: @Crecket: My oh my! `.StartOfLine()` instead of a `^`? `.EndOfLine()` instead of `$`? Well, nice one in general! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to match any number of 1-3 digit sequences separated with a dot (which is optional at the end), you can use

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})*\.?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC9yX0/1)

If you need the numbers to be in the range between `0` and `255` as in IP address, use

```
^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?))*\.?$
```

See another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC9yX0/2).

To limit to only 2 groups of numbers, use a `?` quantifier with the second non-capturing group:

```
^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?))?\.?$
                                                                                       ^
```

See [the 3rd demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC9yX0/3)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, this time it was an all-or-nothing game :)

Comment: I have just one question.. can you explain me this part: **[01]?[1-9][0-9]?** ?

Comment: `[01]?` matches one or zero `0` or `1` digits, `[1-9]` matches exactly one digits from `1` to `9` and `[0-9]?` matches one or zero any digits.